# HoneyWell baseboard thermostat

Tags: electrical, hvac, heating

[image][image]

Hello everyone! Need some help here (trying to help a family member) They recently purchased a home that has a furnace and AC ( with central air) in each room there at these honeywell thermostats. Doing some research, I believe they control some baseboard heating element.

Issue: I can not locate any baseboard heating in any of the rooms. No previous holes in the room or markings anywhere. Each room has normal outlets and no signs of another heating source (except the air vent for the central unit)

does anyone have any clue what this knob controls?
Thank you!!

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. Not having eyes in your house, it's going to be pretty hard for us to figure out what's going on. Have you tested to see if the circuits are live?

Comment: Hello! I have not yet tested. Should that be my free test? If they are dead, im assuming its safe remove.